# count, sum and print total values with awk

Tags: awk

I would like to know how to count the line items, sum their items and finally print the totals, based on `First($1) and Second Field ($2)` combinations.

I am currently able to perform with below steps.

Input.csv

```
mmmm,aa123aa,11,www
pppp,bb456bb,40,www
mmmm,aa123aa,33,www
pppp,bb456bb,20,www
xxxx,cc789cc,88,www
mmmm,aa123aa,22,www
pppp,bb456bb,60,www
mmmm,aa123aa,44,www
xxxx,cc789cc,88,www
```

Step#1:

```
awk -F, '{key=$1","$2;++a[key];b[key]=b[key]+$3} END {for(i in a) print i","a[i]","b[i]}'  Input.csv >Op11_Input.csv
```

Output#1:

Op11_Input.csv

```
xxxx,cc789cc,2,176
mmmm,aa123aa,4,110
pppp,bb456bb,3,120
```

Step#2:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}; {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=(a[i]+=$i)} END {print}' Op11_Input.csv
```

Output#2:

```
0,0,9,406
```

Is there any easiest way, for example a one-liner command, to avoid step2?

Desired Output:

```
xxxx,cc789cc,2,176
mmmm,aa123aa,4,110
pppp,bb456bb,3,120
0,0,9,406
```

I am looking for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
    {key=$1 FS $2; ++a[key]; b[key]+=$3}
    END {
        for(i in a) {print i, a[i], b[i]
                    tot+=a[i]; stot+=b[i]}
        print tot, stot}'  file
```

Note you were using `,` as well as defining the `FS`. I changed it to always use `FS` and `OFS` instead. Also, the addition of fields for the 1st and 2nd doesn't make sense (it outputs `0`) so I just skipped it.

As one liner:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {key=$1 FS $2; ++a[key]; b[key]+=$3} END {for(i in a) {print i, a[i], b[i]; tot+=a[i]; stot+=b[i]} print tot, stot}'  file
xxxx,cc789cc,2,176
mmmm,aa123aa,4,110
pppp,bb456bb,3,120
9,406
```

Even shorter ([thanks Jidder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273787/count-sum-and-print-total-values-with-awk/27273869#comment43019768_27273869)):

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
     {key=$1 FS $2;a[key]++;b[key]+=$3;c+=$3}
     END{for(i in a)print i, a[i], b[i]; print 0, 0, NR,c}' file
```

Comment: Thanks Fedorqui , i have added the addition of fields for the 1st and 2nd Outouts 0 to keep the format in place , while converting and analysing the outputs into Excel , it will be set in the right field position !!!

Comment: @AVN oook then you can use `print 0, 0, tot, stot` in the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot Fedorqui for quick response , Have accepted and up-voted the answer !!!

Comment: Could you not just print `NR` instead of `stot` ?i.e `awk -F, '{key=$1 FS $2;a[key]++;b[key]+=$3;c+=$3} END{for(i in a)print i","a[i]","b[i];print NR","c}'`

Comment: @Jidder indeed. `awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {key=$1 FS $2;a[key]++;b[key]+=$3;c+=$3} END{for(i in a)print i, a[i], b[i]; print 0, 0, NR,c}' file` is fine, good point. Edited with this version as well, thanks!

Comment: Jidder/Fedorqui, how does that NR is equally perform that stot+=b[i] operation , would like to undersatnd , please provide some insight if you get time :)

Comment: @AVN `NR` refers to the number of record. So it is `1` in the first line, `2` in the second and so on... Thus, it contains the number of the last line in the `END` block, so that it can be used to show the number of lines the file contains.